# Why is Ionic social sharing plugin not working?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

When I am trying to use Ionic's social sharing plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing/) I receive the following error message: ERROR: Plugin 'SocialSharing' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.

I am testing on an mobile device (Iphone 7 - IOS 12 - and the error shows up in Xcode).

The way I am trying to open the social share is:

```
this.socialSharing.shareViaFacebook(null, null, link).then(() => {
    console.log('I'm in');
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('err', error);
});
```

In my config.xml I already have:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="5.4.4">
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="24.1.1+" />
</plugin>
```

What could be the cause of this issue ?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you're firing this after your `onDeviceReady` event?

Comment: Yes. The above code is in a function that gets called on the click of a button. So the page loads, I leave it for a few seconds and then click the button.

Comment: same problem, did you solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

The plugin

```
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
```

has an issue in the version you are using and the build fails with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/mj/projects/benara-sales-client/platforms/android/build.gradle' line: 266

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

To fix, you may install v5.4.0

so remove the plugin and the correct version (you have 5.4.4, try 5.4.0)

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-x-social-sharing
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-social-sharing@5.4.0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this still up-to-date? I can see that the latest release of the plugin is 5.6.3 (https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/releases).